# Speech to text in emulator: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to ask how I can use speech to text code on my emulator. My codes work on real device but not work on emulator. The error said :

```
 No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
package net.viralpatel.android.speechtotextdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private TextView txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                    txtText.setText("");
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                txtText.setText(text.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install onto your emulator an app that contains an Activity that handles the `RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`-intent. You might be able to find Google's `VoiceSearch.apk` on the web.

Comment: I install Google voice but it does not work too. If you have working .apk please give url.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain things you can't test using an emulator. Speech to text is on of them.

I'm not sure about this, but you can't use this android feature with the emulator.

No matter what, you should handle this exception with a *try/ catch* an give some feedback to the user.

You can check if there is that `Activity` in current device running your app doing something like:

```
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> infoList = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (infoList.size() == 0) {
             /** Show some feedback to user if there is the activity. Something like "Your device is not abl to run this feature..."*/
        }else{
             /**Your current code goes here.*/
        }
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `com.google.android.voicesearch` application on target device which has no voice recognition activity like:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

if you try to install Google's Search app - it won't help since it doesn't contain the VR engine inside and thus it will try to do the same - install `com.google.android.voicesearch` app but it could fail due to a bug in package name (`pname:com.google.android.voicesearch` instead of just pure package name). However `com.google.android.voicesearch` installation might be impossible due to "Not available in your country".

Answer (score -3):

You might need a virtual SD Card. You can refer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/860b5f346c59f2ca/b94fa1131077321f?lnk=gst&q=microphone%20emulator#b94fa1131077321f)

Comment: but I don't want to record voice I use speech to text like this[http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html] it works on real device but not on emulator why?