# Android - speech to text without stop on silence

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, recognizer-intent

I try to use speech to text. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543249/android-speech-to-text-speech-recognition-voice) is ok, but I don't want to call the intent and use the dialog.

I create a speech recognizer instance and it listens the intent.

```
SpeechRecognizer sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getContext());
sr.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle b) {
            Log.i("TAG", " onResults "); }
        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.i("TAG", " onBeginningOfSpeech ");
        }@Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            Log.i("TAG" , " onRmsChanged " + rmsdB);
        }
        @Override
        ....

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
sr.startListening(intent);
```

When I run this code, onRmsChanged triggers many times. So I comment out `Log.i("TAG" , " onRmsChanged " + rmsdB);`.

onReadyForSpeech -> onBeginningOfSpeech -> onEndOfSpeech -> onResults. But timeout is too short time. 
Now, I want to wait a while in silence. How can I do? It should listen until I call `sr.stoplistening()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Speech Recognition Continuous Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voice Recognition stops listening after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670378/voice-recognition-stops-listening-after-a-few-seconds)